# How to configure Web.config to trace aborted HTTP requests?

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, trace

I am trying to debug an issue on a ASP.NET MVC4 web application that uses IIS 8 where random requests are getting aborted. So far, all other types of debugging have not provided any information about what may be going on. What I know so far is that something is causing a socket connection to be reset which causes the HTTP request to be aborted immediately. I am able to see this when using the Microsoft Message Analyzer tool. This happens a lot more frequently if I set the IIS connection timeout to a lower value, so it seems like it has something to do with a keep alive connection timing out causing a socket reset but not sure.

Anyway, I am trying to set up tracing on my web application such that it will track all of the activity that is happening when a socket connection is reset. So far I've tried enabling net tracing and System.ServiceModel tracing, but all I see are a bunch of Verbose/Information messages that seem normal. I can't find anything unusual going on in those logs. Maybe I am not using the correct tracing sources? What kind of sources or trace config would I use to debug the type of issue I am looking at?